# How to resolve a subdomain to another subdomain of a different host

Tags: domain-name-system

How do I resolve a subdomain to another subdomain of a different host? What I need is

```
sub.firstdomain.com
```

to be resolved as

```
sub2.seconddomain.com
```

I do not have control on secondomain.com(it is a cloud hosting) but I own firstdomain.com

I cannot make  CNAME to point to IP as I cannot resolve the IP of the subdomain.

I used CNAME record BUT it gives me 404 error so I think the forwarding is correct but something is wrong.

So, what can I do? Is there a CNAME tweek? or tip? Is there another way other than CNAME?

Answer (score 2):

- You can't point a CNAME to an IP-Address only to another A record
- You are confusing HTTP Host headers and DNS entries

To explain the second part:

If i set up a VirtualHost that reacts to `firstdomain.invalid` on `192.0.2.1` but don't create a DNS entry I am still able to browse the site by adding the Host headers manually and requestfing from `http://192.0.2.1`.

If I now crate a DNS entry `firstdomain.invalid A 192.0.2.1` I can browse the site by simply using the name (since the HTTP client will take care of the situation that a `Host` header is needed)

If someone crates a DNS entry `seconddomain.invalid A 192.0.2.1` nothing will happen with a browser since the server doesn't know abut the corresponding host entry (setting aside default hosts for now)

If someone creates a DNS entry `seconddomain.invalid CNAME firstdomain.invalid` the same is true as the above. **PLUS** the owner of `seconddomain.invalid` will run into Mail problems since any sane client will see a `CNAME` entry and start resolvoing the MX entries under the domain where `seconddomain.invalid` points to. In other words: the programs will do this:

> Hey there's a CNAME from
>   seconddomain.invalid. It's pointing to
>   firstdomain.invalid. Great I'll just
>   take the MX of firstdomain.invalid
>   since it's a CNAME and try mailing to
>   whatever host is defined there as an
>   MX, if there's no MX defined I'll
>   simply try to mail to the A record of
>   firstdomain.invalid

PS (and totally OT): The .invalid Domain and 192.0.2.0/24 are reserved for documentation and example purposes. Please use those as they are guranteed (by RFC) not to be reachable

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply, but there is no real solution there? what can i do?thanks

Comment: _The people who own the content HTTP server_ have decided that it does not carry the domain `second.example.com.` and have configured it accordingly for the case where anyone goes there asking for WWW pages whose URLs use that domain.  You tell us that you don't own the content HTTP server.  There is nothing that you can do to affect a content HTTP server that isn't yours to reconfigure.

Comment: That is not totally true, you could always use an application layer proxz (read squid) to provide the simple case. Of course you could always hack something up to rewrite the content so it looks like your own -- but that would be...unethical